# Apache mod_proxy_fcgi and PHP-FPM (php-cgi.exe) issue (No input file specified.) on Windows

Tags: php, apache

The following is PHP-FPM (PHP 5.5)

```
php-cgi.exe -b 127.0.0.1:9000
```

The following is mod_proxy_fcgi (Apache 2.4)

The first way

```
<Files ~ "\.(php|phtml)$">
    SetHandler "proxy:fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000/"
</Files>
```

The second way

```
<LocationMatch ^(.*\.(php|phtml))$>
    ProxyPass fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000/$1
</LocationMatch>
```

The third way

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
    RewriteRule ^([^\.]+\.(php|phtml))$ fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000/$1 [P,L]
</IfModule>
```

The above three ways will get an error "No input file specified." Anybody know why? How should I do to solve this problem?

Comment: Can you run with LogLevel debug proxy_fcgi:trace8 and/or send requests to this dummy debug FCGI?

https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=51517#c3

Comment: If you use `telnet localhost 9000` do you then get through? Is the port actually open?

Comment: Did you manage to fix it? I'm with ApacheLounge 2.4.26 and I'm experiencing the same issue.

Comment: I'm experiecing the same issue. None of the three ways worked for me. Is it possible to use ProxyPass for a specific folder only? It is not allowed to use this directive inside a <Directory> section.

Answer (score 8):

Inexplicably, simply changing the trailing `/` to a `#` seems to fix the problem:

```
<Files ~ "\.(php|phtml)$">
    SetHandler "proxy:fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000#"
</Files>
```

In trying to understand this I set Apache to `LogLevel debug` (timestamp/module/process details removed for brevity):

- Using `/` gives:

  ```
  mod_proxy_fcgi.c(911): [client ::1:60730] AH01076: url: fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000/E:/test/webroot/test.php proxyname: (null) proxyport: 0
  mod_proxy_fcgi.c(920): [client ::1:60730] AH01078: serving URL fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000/E:/test/webroot/test.php
  proxy_util.c(2154): AH00942: FCGI: has acquired connection for (*)
  proxy_util.c(2208): [client ::1:60730] AH00944: connecting fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000/E:/test/webroot/test.php to 127.0.0.1:9000
  proxy_util.c(2417): [client ::1:60730] AH00947: connected /E:/test/webroot/test.php to 127.0.0.1:9000
  ```
- Using `#` gives:

  ```
  mod_proxy_fcgi.c(911): [client ::1:60738] AH01076: url: fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000#E:/test/webroot/test.php proxyname: (null) proxyport: 0
  mod_proxy_fcgi.c(920): [client ::1:60738] AH01078: serving URL fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000#E:/test/webroot/test.php
  proxy_util.c(2154): AH00942: FCGI: has acquired connection for (*)
  proxy_util.c(2208): [client ::1:60738] AH00944: connecting fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000#E:/test/webroot/test.php to 127.0.0.1:9000
  proxy_util.c(2417): [client ::1:60738] AH00947: connected  to 127.0.0.1:9000
  ```

The crucial difference appears to be in the last line, where the second (working) method doesn't appear to log *anything* as the value passed to the PHP process.

I'm at a loss to explain this and can't find mention of it anywhere. (Perhaps a braver soul than I would be willing to delve into the Apache and/or PHP source to investigate.)

Note that I haven't tested this beyond running `phpinfo()` so wouldn't recommend it for a production server.

---

***Edit***

This works for PHP 7.0, but with PHP 5.6 I still get the 'No input file specified' error.

***Edit 2***

And working with Apache 2.4.25, but not the recently released 2.4.26!

This seems to be an incompatibility minefield that is explicitly mentioned in the CHANGES_2.4.26 file:

> mod_proxy_fcgi: Return to 2.4.20-and-earlier behavior of leaving
>        a "proxy:fcgi://" prefix in the SCRIPT_FILENAME environment variable by
>        default.  Add ProxyFCGIBackendType to allow the type of backend to be
>        specified so these kinds of fixups can be restored without impacting
>        FPM. PR60576 [Eric Covener, Jim Jagielski]

The [documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy_fcgi.html#proxyfcgibackendtype) has been updated to reflect this:

> One example of values that change based on the setting of this directive is SCRIPT_FILENAME. When using mod_proxy_fcgi historically, SCRIPT_FILENAME was prefixed with the string "proxy:fcgi://". This variable is what some generic FastCGI applications would read as their script input, but PHP-FPM would strip the prefix then remember it was talking to Apache. In 2.4.21 through 2.4.25, this prefix was automatically stripped by the server, breaking the ability of PHP-FPM to detect and interoperate with Apache in some scenarios.

Comment: Thanks @timclutton ! Long story short: it's not really doable in a production enviroment :-(

Comment: That would by my conclusion, yes. I personally use [`mod_fcgid`](http://httpd.apache.org/mod_fcgid/) instead of `mod_proxy_fcgi` and that works well.

Comment: Did you guys consider setting `ProxyFCGIBackendType GENERIC` as it is described at https://www.orbitale.io/2017/11/11/apache-and-php-fpm-in-windows.html at the very bottom? This worked for me.

Answer (score 5):

I think this is a bug in mod_proxy_fcgi, connected to an issue resolved in  Apache 2.4.12 onwards:

mod_proxy_fcgi: Remove proxy:balancer:// prefix from SCRIPT_FILENAME   passed to fastcgi backends. [Eric Covener]

[Here is a link](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/httpd-cvs/201412.mbox/%3C20141219140353.875D7AC08A8@hades.apache.org%3E)

Unfortunatelly it was not good enough as Apache is sending the SCRIPT_FILENAME with a starting slash, similar to **\c:\fileName.php**, which is not resolved as a local file name and is never executed. You may verify this using a network sniffer(Wireshark) listening on your FastCGI port.

I will be more than happy to see this issue resolved officially since I am not confident in recompiling Apache by myself and so I am using distributions from *apachelounge*.

Comment: I think too but my Apache version is 2.4.18 from Apache Lounge

Comment: It is fixed? Is there a reported bug? Or it's still not possible to deal with drive letters in mod_proxy_fcgi in Windows?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you didn't get me right.

Before the fix it was:  **proxy:balancer://\c:\fileName.php**

After the fix it is: **\c:\fileName.php**

Which are both invalid file names in Windows, while thinking Linux there is no drive letter there so it becomes **\fileName.php** which is valid. The fix would be to remove the starting slash and recompile.

Comment: Please don't create new account for each answer. edit the same answer

Answer (score 2):

I was getting this error when following the steps indicated here to run PHP under Apache on Windows via FastCGI:

https://www.orbitale.io/2017/11/11/apache-and-php-fpm-in-windows.html

After setting up php-cgi.exe as a service on port 9000 (using NSSM) and setting httpd.conf to handle php files as such:

```
<IfModule dir_module>
    DirectoryIndex index.php index.html
</IfModule>

<Files ~ "\.php$">
    SetHandler "proxy:fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000#"
</Files>
```

I was getting this same error when navigating to localhost (which contained an index.php with a simple `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` .

I was getting worried until I tried editing my php.ini where I defined the doc_root directive:

```
doc_root = C:\Apache24\htdocs
```

Having done that and having restarted my Apache service, voilà I got the php info page!
I'm using PHP 7.3.5 NTS x64 with Apache 2.4 x64.

Comment: This is what fixed it for me. This works with PHP 5.6.40, Apache HTTPD 2.4.48 x64, Windows 10. Thanks, John!

Answer (score 1):

```
LoadModule proxy_fcgi_module modules/mod_proxy_fcgi.so
<Files ~ "\.(php|phtml)$">
    SetHandler "proxy:fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000//./"
    ProxyFCGIBackendType GENERIC
</Files>
```

You will got log like this:

```
proxy_util.c(2208): [client ::1:60730] AH00944: connecting fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000//./E:/test/webroot/test.php to 127.0.0.1:9000
proxy_util.c(2417): [client ::1:60730] AH00947: connected //./E:/test/webroot/test.php to 127.0.0.1:9000
```

Because in windows, `E:\test\webroot\test.php` is valid, and `\\.\E:\test\webroot\test.php` is also valid, which is called DOS device paths.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, apache would not set SCRIPT_FILENAME properly.
This fixed it:

```
ProxyFCGISetEnvIf "true" SCRIPT_FILENAME "%{reqenv:DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{reqenv:SCRIPT_NAME}"
```

The reason is probably that this variable normally starts with a slash, which creates invalid path strings in Windows because absolute paths don't start with a slash here. PHP then generates the utterly useless "No input file specified" error instead of a more descriptive not found error.

Note that there is no unconditional `ProxyFCGISetEnv`, so we use `ProxyFCGISetEnvIf` with a condition of `true`