# Getting "No input file specified." when trying to set up PHP-FPM under Apache 2.4 (Windows)

Tags: php, windows, mod-proxy, apache2.4

I'm not having success in setting up PHP-FPM in a specific folder of Apache 2.4 HTTP server.

I've tried to use all three ways to set up PHP-FPM like in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36415930/apache-mod-proxy-fcgi-and-php-fpm-php-cgi-exe-issue-no-input-file-specified) but all of them resulted in "No input file specified."

I already have PHP 5.6 running as a module in Apache 2.4 server (Windows).
I would like to upgrade PHP to 7.3.4 for all applications on the server but many of them are not currently ready for this. The decision was to have two PHP versions running at the same time.

PHP 5.4.60 will continue to run as a Apache 2.4 module

PHP 7.3.4 will run as PHP-FPM for specific folder 'd:/www/htdocs/php7/'

I have already run PHP-FPM with:

```
php-cgi -b localhost:8734
```

(I have also used -C option in the command above but result did not change)

Extract of httpd.conf:

```
    <VirtualHost *:80>
        DocumentRoot "d:/www/htdocs/"
        <Directory "d:/www/htdocs/php7/">
            <Files ~ "\.(php|phtml)$">
                SetHandler "proxy:fcgi://localhost:8734/"
            </Files>
        </Directory>
    </VirtualHost>
```

Apache error log shows (among other 'sending env var' lines):

```
    [proxy:debug] [pid 1308:tid 760] mod_proxy.c(1246): [client 10.16.32.48:49607] AH01143: Running scheme fcgi handler (attempt 0)
    [proxy_ajp:debug] [pid 1308:tid 760] mod_proxy_ajp.c(739): [client 10.16.32.48:49607] AH00894: declining URL fcgi://localhost:8734/D:/www/htdocs/html/phpinfo.php
    [proxy_fcgi:debug] [pid 1308:tid 760] mod_proxy_fcgi.c(1019): [client 10.16.32.48:49607] AH01076: url: fcgi://localhost:8734/D:/www/htdocs/html/phpinfo.php proxyname: (null) proxyport: 0
    [proxy_fcgi:debug] [pid 1308:tid 760] mod_proxy_fcgi.c(1028): [client 10.16.32.48:49607] AH01078: serving URL fcgi://localhost:8734/D:/www/htdocs/html/phpinfo.php
    [proxy:debug] [pid 1308:tid 760] proxy_util.c(2317): AH00942: FCGI: has acquired connection for (*)
    [proxy:debug] [pid 1308:tid 760] proxy_util.c(2371): [client 10.16.32.48:49607] AH00944: connecting fcgi://localhost:8734/D:/www/htdocs/html/phpinfo.php to localhost:8734
    [proxy:debug] [pid 1308:tid 760] proxy_util.c(2580): [client 10.16.32.48:49607] AH00947: connected  to localhost:8734
    [proxy:trace2] [pid 1308:tid 760] proxy_util.c(3014): FCGI: fam 2 socket created to connect to *
    [proxy:debug] [pid 1308:tid 760] proxy_util.c(3046): AH02824: FCGI: connection established with 127.0.0.1:8734 (*)
    ... (many 'sending env var' lines) ...
    [proxy_fcgi:trace8] [pid 1308:tid 760] mod_proxy_fcgi.c(680): [client 10.16.32.48:49607] .....s..         0106000100730500                
    [proxy_fcgi:trace4] [pid 1308:tid 760] util_script.c(568): [client 10.16.32.48:49607] Headers from script 'phpinfo.php':
    [proxy_fcgi:trace4] [pid 1308:tid 760] util_script.c(571): [client 10.16.32.48:49607]   Status: 404 Not Found
    [proxy_fcgi:trace4] [pid 1308:tid 760] util_script.c(571): [client 10.16.32.48:49607]   X-Powered-By: PHP/7.3.4
    [proxy_fcgi:trace4] [pid 1308:tid 760] util_script.c(571): [client 10.16.32.48:49607]   Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
    [proxy_fcgi:trace8] [pid 1308:tid 760] mod_proxy_fcgi.c(680): [client 10.16.32.48:49607] FastCGI header (8 bytes)
    [proxy_fcgi:trace8] [pid 1308:tid 760] mod_proxy_fcgi.c(680): [client 10.16.32.48:49607] ........         0103000100080000                
    [proxy:debug] [pid 1308:tid 760] proxy_util.c(2332): AH00943: FCGI: has released connection for (*)
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: No, you have not run php-fpm. You ran php-cgi, which is for CGI, not FastCGI, two very different protocols.

Comment: You must have misunderstood something. php-fpm is the FastCGI Process Manager, and generally preferable over CGI. php-cgi is the older CGI sapi. I have never heard that php-fpm doesn't work on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

For the same error message (no input file selected) another reason can be if you applied "open_basedir" restriction incorrectly, which prevents you from opening the php file. You should see some indication in the log.